# Android shortcut position

Tags: android, shortcut

i have a question: is it possible to set the position of a shortcut inside the wallpaper?
i have done some search but i don't found nothing relevant.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it CellX and CellY and Page number? It can be changed in Launcher, we cannot explicitly set from external application.

Comment: Can you explain better or give some links? Thanks ^_^

Comment: Do you want to change these values from external app?

Comment: I create a shortcut for my app and i want to set its position if possible.My app is external (not in android firmware).is com.android.launcher the "Launcher" you talk about?

Comment: Yes, it is com.android.launcher package